# Gmail uses its sending account address as the reply-to, rather than person filling out the inquiry form

Tags: c#, email, gmail

I have several inquiry forms that I'd like to use a Gmail account to authenticate and send through. The forms send successfully, but the reply-to address is always the Gmail account, rather than the person's e-mail who filled out the form.  This is a problem for the client in that they can't hit "Reply" without changing the reply-to address.

I've poked around the Gmail account and don't see anything that appears switch anything on and off to fix this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is a restriction when using gmail as your SMTP server. You could use a different SMTP server to send the emails like MailDrill or MailGun.

OR

...and I'm not sure this will work. You can configure your gmail account to allow you to send emails with a different reply address/alias, but each address requires confirmation.

The steps to do this are [located here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

EDIT: I just re-read your message. Since you're using form data for the address I think your only option may be to use an alternate SMTP server.

Sorry I don't have a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, man... that's my understanding as well, but thought I'd ask in case anyone knows a work-around.